# selectAllText deselectAllText bootstrap select

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-4, struts-1

I am working on an application struts 1/HTML. The idea is to make the website responsive using bootstrap 4. I have an issue when trying to add options using javascript. The "All" and "none" are not displayed. [Screenshot of menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3uAG.jpg)

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="EN" lang="EN">
<head>
    <title><mfb:message key="registration.title"/></title>


    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"
            integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg=="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/d1ed746900.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.18/js/i18n/defaults-en_US.min.js"
            integrity="sha512-m8hWkNWHy3+ItOW2VjI5JEpu04AXwLMef1xho55Pmw9pdwocACt8wYo/+yznN3o5JqYcmHOHe7x6Th5cEcqZsA=="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <select class="selectpicker " multiple>
        <option data-hidden="true">Select</option>
        <option data-subtext="AUS">Australia</option>
        <option data-subtext="INA">Indonesia</option>
        <option data-subtext="IND">India</option>
        <option data-subtext="GBR">United Kingdom</option>
        <option data-subtext="USA">United States of America</option>
    </select>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
                style: 'btn-select',
                selectAllText: 'All',
                deselectAllText: 'None'
            });
            $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please, do you have an idea. Thank you.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: I need to reuse the existing code using JQuery multi-select plugin and make it responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Only need to add a "multiple" attribute to the select header:
https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/examples/#multiple-select-boxes

**UPDATE:**
I found the reason it didn't work so far: You forget to includes the bootstrap-select plugin resources(css and js files) to your code:
https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/#quick-start

My working example (external resources in under Settings):

```
https://codepen.io/adampweb/pen/jOMmwPO
```

Comment: Sorry, I have forgotten to add multiple in the question. What is on the screenshot is what I get when I add multiple.

Comment: I updated my answer, in short: You forget to includes the bootstrap-select plugin resources(css and js files) to your code

Comment: Actually, I had the  bootstrap-select plugin added. It is because, it was not only mentionned in the example. I had a problem with JQuery versions. I had a non updated version and a new version for bootsrap. That's why it did not work. Now, I have another issue that I have updated.